# Javascript Mobile Device Position

Tags: javascript

Is there were an easier way of finding the position of a mobile device? Currently, when an acceleration event fires, I need to add the acceleration to a position variable, like this:

```
var px, py, pz;

function handleMotionEvent(event) {
    var x = event.acceleration.x;
    var y = event.acceleration.y;
    var z = event.acceleration.z;

    px+=x;
    py+=y;
    pz+=z;
}
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", handleMotionEvent, true);
```

Is what I'm doing the only solution, or is there a position-change listener that does this perhaps more efficiently? The code really doesn't work in general, because the acceleration is returned so, unless the phone is moving at a constant acceleration the whole time (which it isn't), the code wouldn't be effective.

Comment: Do you want the position?  Or orientation?

Comment: I'd like the position of the phone. The orientation is rather easy to obtain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: The accelerometers of mobile devices are not accurate enough to determine position.  You must use the GPS to determine position.

Comment: I'm trying to determine position locally. I'm making an application which sends the phone's location data with SockJS to a desktop computer, and it's displayed on the screen. The code above doesn't quite work, as the coordinates aren't accurate. I'm not trying to display the location on a large scale, but rather in feet. If I move my phone a foot to the left, I want the position to that scale. Not in terms of latitude/longitude. Is there no solution at all?

Comment: Not with the built-in accelerometers, no.  They are far too inaccurate and aren't sampled at a high enough rate.